# "Patent" tag - Why we don't have it?

Tags: discussion, tags

Why does this site doesn't has a "patent" tag? Is that completely unrelated to the site?
How come it is unrelated? There are many papers which presents ideas that can be patented.

Comment: As @eykanal commented [here](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3169/intellectual-property-on-performing-old-art#comment5198_3169), there is a StackExchange site called [Ask Patents](http://patents.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If a tag doesn't exist, it doesn't mean it's not important or unrelated to the site. It's probably because nobody's asked a question about that topic yet.

In the present instance, we have the "intellectual property" tag, which would presumably cover patents as well.